# A <div> with 100% site-height (not window height)

Tags: css

I'm already searching for 2 hours now, and still haven't found an answer to my problem.
I just want to know how to give a DIV the height of the full page and not from the window?

This is my HTML, and the table is bigger than the page you see (so you have to scroll down to see the last pictures).

But how do I get the DIV id="container" to expand over the full size of the site? 
The div has to overlap the table, that is the reason why the table isn't inside of the div.

 Here's a fiddle:
 
http://jsfiddle.net/mWFGZ/

Comment: You put everything inside the body inside that `div`, that's how.

Comment: And please, don't use tables for layout.

Comment: Why do you open the container div and close it right after you open it? Isn't it supposed to be after the /table tag?

Comment: This sentence is a bit confusing: "full size of the site"...

Comment: I know, but the div has to appear on top of the rest of the body :) So it covers the table and you dont see the images anymore :) sorry forgot to mention that :) The div will get more stuff inside later on.
@William: If I do "min-height = 100%" @ body, html and the div, it only covers the part you see at first. When you scroll down the div isn't covering everything below. So it only covers the window.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/mWFGZ/ please.

Comment: @Milaan: Can't you simply change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed` in your demo?

Comment: @thirtydot That is indeed possible but what if I don't want the contents of the div to be fixed? When I scroll down the "/* some stuff is going to be here later on */" has to disappear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/mWFGZ/1/

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
body {
    position: relative
}
#container{
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0
}
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you very much! The problem was that my body didn't had the "position:relative;". It works perfectly now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your div around the table, this would make the div grow with the table or you could use a simple javascript to get the height of the table and set you div's height.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I forgot to mention (I'll edit the first post in a minute) that the DIV had to be on top of the table. It overlaps the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
#container{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```